# what is the error in following code

Tags: mysql

What is error in the following code of joining

```
select s1.name,s1.roll_no,c1.fee_amount 
 FROM s1.student,c1.Class 
  where s1.class_id=c1.class_id;
```

Comment: What is the error message? What is the DB structure?

Comment: select s1.name,s1.roll_no,c1.fee_amount FROM student s1,Class c1 where s1.class_id=c1.class_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT s1.name,s1.roll_no,c1.fee_amount 
FROM student s1,Class c1 
WHERE s1.class_id=c1.class_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly placed aliases for table names:

It should be:

```
select s1.name,s1.roll_no,c1.fee_amount 
FROM student s1, Class c1
where s1.class_id=c1.class_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT s1.name,s1.roll_no,c1.fee_amount 
FROM student s1, Class c1 
WHERE s1.class_id=c1.class_id;
```

remove "." at the table which u want to replace name.